# How do I hide grub boot menu unless shift is pressed?

Tags: grub2

I've read the forum but it seems my grub boot menu doesn't follow the form of the config file.

I would like the menu to not appear unless <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed.

My grub menu appears every boot and stays there until you select a menu item.

My current `/etc/default/grub` is:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomdmonddf nomdmonisw"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_FORCE_HIDDEN_MENU="true"
export GRUB_FORCE_HIDDEN_MENU
```

(I've tried the `true`'s with both quotes and no quotes, it makes no difference)

I've also done `update-grub` and `update-grub2`.

Can anyone please tell me why, when my system boots, it just sits at a Grub menu? It's a headless system which isn't good as I have to add a keyboard to get it to reboot.

This is not a dual-boot system.

Comment: OK there's a bigger problem here. After some digging, it seems that the update-grub works and creates the grub.cfg file, however grub2 is not loading it when the machine boots. How do I find out what grub is actually loading?

Comment: I know the last two lines for the config can be used with Arch Linux, but personally I'm not sure if Ubuntu uses them.

Comment: Just because I found it difficult to find, and immensely helpful, here's the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html

Answer (score 3):

[My answer from AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/646743/265381):

> You need to use the GRUB **holdshift** script.
>
> If you read the GRUB man carefully you will notice that what you want is not achievable via standard settings.
>
> Just download the script here [GRUB holdshift](https://askubuntu.com/a/646743/265381) and follow the instructions in the readme.

Answer (score 1):

Around the time this question was asked, Debian started to ship an Ubuntu patch for "quick boot".

https://salsa.debian.org/grub-team/grub/-/blob/master/debian/patches/quick-boot.patch

I also know Manjaro and Fedora (where it's called auto-hide) followed along.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file to see if the changes are being passed when running `sudo update-grub`. The `sudo update-grub` command is suppose to update `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` from `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/grub.d` when ran. If it is not then you can temporarily edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to make it work, but it might be overwritten when the kernel is upgraded or `update-grub` is run again.

If you check `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and the changes have been applied and it's still not working, the problem is probably the setting, but as I see them now they look correct.

Comment: Sorry...I didn't see your comment until after I wrote this answer.

Comment: I've found the issue, although I still don't know how to fix it. Do you think I should put this into a new thread?

Comment: Basically, I have an HP N40L microserver, with 2 identical drives, I use the system to hardware raid them as a mirror. I then installed mint on the system about a year ago. This has been running perfectly, updating, etc. until I upgraded to Mint 17. I thought everything was fine, but I've noticed that mint is only using 1 of the drives to boot, then for some reason was showing the contents of the other drive.

Comment: i.e. it boots sdb1, but "df" shows sda1. I'm SURE df used to show a /dev/mapper/<blahblah> drive which was the raid array. Thus any updates to grub go to sda1, but it boots sdb1 then loads the fs sda1.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following lines in the file `/etc/default/grub` :

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0.0

GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.0
```

Finally run `update-grub`.